# ERROR: No matching distribution found for scipy==1.7.1

Tags: python, numpy, pip, scipy, apple-m1

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement scipy==1.7.1 (from versions: 0.8.0, 0.9.0, 0.10.0, 0.10.1, 0.11.0, 0.12.0, 0.12.1, 0.13.0, 0.13.1, 0.13.2, 0.13.3, 0.14.0, 0.14.1, 0.15.0, 0.15.1, 0.16.0, 0.16.1, 0.17.0, 0.17.1, 0.18.0, 0.18.1, 0.19.0, 0.19.1, 1.0.0b1, 1.0.0rc1, 1.0.0rc2, 1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.1.0rc1, 1.1.0, 1.2.0rc1, 1.2.0rc2, 1.2.0, 1.2.1, 1.2.2, 1.2.3, 1.3.0rc1, 1.3.0rc2, 1.3.0, 1.3.1, 1.3.2, 1.3.3, 1.4.0rc1, 1.4.0rc2, 1.4.0, 1.4.1, 1.5.0rc1, 1.5.0rc2, 1.5.0, 1.5.1, 1.5.2, 1.5.3, 1.5.4, 1.6.0rc1, 1.6.0rc2, 1.6.0, 1.6.1, 1.6.2, 1.6.3, 1.7.0rc1, 1.7.0rc2, 1.7.0, 1.7.1)

Getting this error as I'm trying to install all the packages required from a git repo in a virtual environment. This specific error is from the package `scipy==1.7.1` I have upgraded pip and python to its latest version but still getting this result. For some reason this installment works perfectly fine on my other windows PC, but doesn't work on my Mac M1.

Python version: 3.9.7

Pip version: 21.2.4

Comment: have you tried installing it manually ? see [scipy files](https://pypi.org/project/scipy/#files)

Comment: @AcaNg I tried to download each of the mac version .whl file type and put it in my env folder then run the code `pip install "filename"`, but then I get this error: `ERROR: scipy-1.7.1-cp39-cp39-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.`

Comment: have a look at this discussion on github : https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/13102#issuecomment-733988544

Comment: @cizario For some reason I was only able to install scipy via miniconda... After running `conda install scipy` in the root system, and then running `pip install scipy` in the venv, it works. Issue is resolved! Thank you.

Comment: In the question, it is unclear if there is some version pinning of dependencies due to some other requirements in the git repo. Try to isolate the error more. Can you install scipy 1.7.1 in a fresh venv? Or is the problem only for this specific git repo?

Answer (score 0):

I am getting the same error when installing a wheel in WinPython that requires SciPy 1.7.1. The **complete** error message says:

> ERROR: Ignored the following versions that require a different python
> version: 1.6.2 Requires-Python >=3.7,<3.10; 1.6.3 Requires-Python
> >=3.7,<3.10; 1.7.0 Requires-Python >=3.7,<3.10; 1.7.0rc1 Requires-Python >=3.7,<3.10; 1.7.0rc2 Requires-Python >=3.7,<3.10;
> 1.7.1 Requires-Python >=3.7,<3.10
>
> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement
> scipy==1.7.1 (from sun-stack-tools) (from versions: 0.8.0, 0.9.0,
> 0.10.0, 0.10.1, 0.11.0, 0.12.0, 0.12.1, 0.13.0, 0.13.1, 0.13.2, 0.13.3, 0.14.0, 0.14.1, 0.15.0, 0.15.1, 0.16.0, 0.16.1, 0.17.0, 0.17.1, 0.18.0, 0.18.1, 0.19.0, 0.19.1, 1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.1.0, 1.2.0, 1.2.1, 1.2.2, 1.2.3, 1.3.0rc1, 1.3.0rc2, 1.3.0, 1.3.1, 1.3.2, 1.3.3, 1.4.0rc1, 1.4.0rc2, 1.4.0, 1.4.1, 1.5.0rc1, 1.5.0rc2, 1.5.0, 1.5.1, 1.5.2, 1.5.3, 1.5.4, 1.6.0rc1, 1.6.0rc2, 1.6.0, 1.6.1, 1.7.2, 1.7.3, 1.8.0rc1, 1.8.0rc2, 1.8.0rc3, 1.8.0rc4, 1.8.0, 1.8.1, 1.9.0rc1, 1.9.0rc2, 1.9.0rc3, 1.9.0, 1.9.1)
>
> ERROR: No matching distribution found for scipy==1.7.1

I am using Python version 3.10.2, which is >= 3.10.
So the problem is obviously, that Scipy version 1.7.1 (along with versions 1.6.2, 1.6.3., 1.7.0 and 1.7.0rc2) requires Python versions from 1.7.0 to 1.9.x. Earlier and later versions of SciPy don't have these requirements.

The reason for this is, that [SciPy 1.6.2](https://scipy.github.io/devdocs/release.1.6.2.html) was "the first SciPy release to place upper bounds on some dependencies to improve the long-term repeatability of source builds" (see also [here](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/pull/12862)). [SciPy 1.7.2](https://scipy.github.io/devdocs/release.1.7.2.html) was the first version to support Python versions from 3.10.

Answer (score -1):

You can remove version from requirements.txt file
Check your numpy version also in requirments.txt file

try:

```
pip install sciPy
conda install -c anaconda scipy
```

or
or if you are using python2 try this

```
pip3 install -e
```